# Jenkins: "TF command line executable" does not look into MAC slave's path to find the tf.exe

Tags: tfs, jenkins, master-slave

I had set up a MAC slave and have downloaded Team Explorer everywhere on MAC slave. I did set up the path on both slave and master. The TF command runs fine if I go into the slave machine and run it. The problem is, when I just type "tf" in the "TF command line executable" Jenkins refuses to look into the path of MAC slave. It only looks into the windows master's path. This is the error I get:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "tf" (in directory "/build/workspace/Aries_Mac"): error=2, No such file or directory

The reason I know that Jenkins does not look into the mac path is, I have tried putting in the mac path manually. This is what Jenkins shows me:

> TF command line executable
>
> There's no such executable /build/TEE-CLC in PATH: C:/Windows/system32, C:/Windows, C:/Windows/System32/Wbem, C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/, C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn/, c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft ASP.NET/ASP.NET Web Pages/v1.0/, C:/Program Files/Microsoft/Web Platform Installer/, C:/Program Files/nodejs/, C:/Program Files/Npm/npm, C:/flex-build/apache-ant-1.8.4/bin, C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Windows Performance Toolkit/, C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin, C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/cmd, C:/Program Files/Git/cmd, C:/tools/python2, C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE.*

But if I still save the configuration, I don't get the java.io.IOException error anymore. This confirms that if I input the MAC's TF path manually even though the "TF command line" doesn't pick it up, it works fine. But, obviously it breaks my windows jobs.

I have tried almost everything I knew, I have set up paths, I have restarted Jenkins several times. I ran the `tf eula -accept` command on slave by logging into the slave machine. I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Do people abbreviate "Macintosh" as "MAC" or as "Mac"? I saw "MAC" in your question and thought of Media Access Control.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I meant Macintosh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, before I post the workaround I want to say that I did change the path that Jenkins uses. (/etc/profile). I even tried adding environment variable PATH in my slave configuration but none of that worked. I just couldn't get the tf command working from the plugin. If I executed the tf from shell it worked fine. echo $PATH command showed me the path that I added, but, I just couldn't get the plugin working for me.

Workaround: I copied and pasted my files from Team Explorer Everywhere into the /bin folder. This solves the problem and the plugin works fine. This is not a nice way to do it but this solution works till I am able to find a better one.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins runs as `jenkins` user on Linux based systems (including Mac). You have to add the path to `jenkins` user, not your logged in user.

Comment: I did add path to the Jenkins user. I have even added path for all the users on Mac.

Comment: Type `echo $PATH` in your Execute Shell on Mac Slave from Jenkins

Comment: Ok, so I typed echo $PATH. I got the path info, but, I couldn't see the path to "Tf" that I set up on Mac. I have set up the path for all users on Mac by using: sudo pico /etc/paths. When I echo $PATH by logging into the machine as different users, I do see my added path for all users I log in as. Now I am a bit confused what user my Mac_slave is running under since I don't see my added path. I have created a separate user for it and under system information the user.name shows me the exact same user name that I created. So I am assuming that my Mac-Slave is running under that user.

Comment: Restart the slave (process). The environment configuration, including the path, is forked once at the time of environment creation. I don't know much about setting paths for Macs, but that is your issue here (as you verified). Worst case, you can always configure a global path variable in Jenkins global configuration.

Comment: Well, I set up my Mac Slave again and did the echo $PATH via Jenkins. This time I could see my path that I set up, but unfortunately my problem with "TF.exe" still persists. So, I guess there isn't a problem with path. Like I posted in the question, Jenkins just refuses to look into my Mac_slave to find the path of "Tf.exe".